# how to know whether we are scrolling the page or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, gsap

**How to detect mouse scroll event, how to get a state where we know that we're not currently doing the scrolling. How to create react custom hook out of that situation. the hook is going to produce false state if there's no scroll event going on, and true state for the opposite situation.**

I've used setTimeout for this problem before but the result was not quiet what I want.
the code looks like this when using setTimeout

```
  const [isWheeling, setIsWheeling] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let scrollEndTimer;
    const wheelTimer = () => {
      setIsWheeling(true)

      clearTimeout(scrollEndTimer)
      scrollEndTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      // setTimeout(() => {
        setIsWheeling(false)
      }, 300)
    }

    window.addEventListener('wheel', wheelTimer)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('wheel', wheelTimer)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isWheeling) {
      gsap.to(svgHeightRef.current, {
        value: 200,
        duration: 0.5 
      })
    } else {
      gsap.to(svgHeightRef.current, {
        value: 500,
        duration: 1
      })
    }

  }, [isWheeling])
```

it does not behave the way I want it to, there might be something wrong with the way I implement the setTimeout.

The issue is simply how to detect whether I move my mouse wheel or not. If I do nothing with the mouse wheel, give me false state, and whenever I touch my wheel, it gives me true state right away.

Can anyone help me regarding of this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import * as React from 'react'

export const useIsScrolling = (target = document) => {
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = React.useState(false)
  const on = React.useCallback(() => setIsScrolling(true), [])
  const off = React.useCallback(() => setIsScrolling(false), [])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    target.addEventListener('scroll', on, { passive: true })
    target.addEventListener('scrollend', off)
    return () => {
      target?.removeEventListener('scroll', on)
      target?.removeEventListener('scrollend', off)
    }
  }, [])

  return isScrolling
}
```

Use as

```js
// document scrolling:
const isScrolling = useIsSCrolling()

// or, with a specific target element:
const isScrolling = useIsScrolling(
  document.querySelector('your-selector-here')
)
```

Demo:

```js
const useIsScrolling = (target = document) => {
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = React.useState(false)
  const on = React.useCallback(() => setIsScrolling(true), [])
  const off = React.useCallback(() => setIsScrolling(false), [])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    target.addEventListener('scroll', on, { passive: true })
    target.addEventListener('scrollend', off)
    return () => {
      target && target.removeEventListener('scroll', on)
      target && target.removeEventListener('scrollend', off)
    }
  }, [])

  return isScrolling
}

const App = () => {
  const isScrolling = useIsScrolling()
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify({ isScrolling }, null, 2)}</pre>
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />)
```

```css
#root {
  height: 800vh;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #fff,
    #fff 30px,
    #f5f5f5 30px,
    #f5f5f5 60px
  );
}
pre {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Notes:

- Safari and some mobile browsers do not support `scrollend` event on either [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scrollend_event#browser_compatibility) or [`element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollend_event#browser_compatibility).
  If you need this to work in those browsers, you'll need to use [a polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@af-utils/scrollend-polyfill) - there might be others, but this one comes up first, so I guess it's most used.
- the optional chaining on removing the events is needed for cases where the initial `target` is no longer present in DOM when your component is unmounted.
- if using Next, this will only work as expected on client side components
- in general, running code on `scroll` listeners can cause performance issues. It is not the case here, as I used a passive scroll listener.
- `scroll` event does not bubble ***<sup>1</sup>***. It is important you get the `target` right for this to work (e.g: if the scrolling happens in some app container and you bind on `document` or `window` it won't work as expected).
- the above code covers all cases of scrolling, not only `wheel` based scrolling (keyboard based, touch based, other pointer scrolling methods and programmatic scrolling), with two conditions:

  - the target is scrollable and actually scrolled (otherwise `scroll` event never fires, even if the pointer/keyboard/touch event is performed)
  - `.preventDefault()` is not called on the triggering event (e.g: `wheel`, `touchstart`, etc)

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - with one exception: when the user scrolls the `document`, `scroll` and `scrollend` are triggered on both `document` and `window`.

Comment: do they have the same thing for wheel event ?

Comment: like 'wheelend' ? @tao

Comment: Nope. But `wheel` triggers both `scroll` and `scrollend`. With some conditions: a) the target needs to be scrollable (e.g: there has to be actual scrolling); b) you don't call `.preventDefault()` on the `wheel` event, in any listener. Note the code I posted catches all types of scrolling (touch based, pointer based, keyboard based). `wheel` is just one of the pointer based methods of scrolling.

Comment: Here is a [comprehensive list of existing DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events). Each of them has a link to the HTML Standards specification for that event (the official definition) which, in theory, browsers should respect to the letter.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, appreciate that very much

Comment: @ReynaldLamury, the proper way to express appreciation for a [SO] answer is to upvote it. Not so much as a curtesy to the answerer, but as a curtesy to future users having a similar problem, effectively telling them *"this answer has relevant and useful information about the question being asked"*. Upvoted answers also increase the question's indexing on the terms used in the question's title and tags, making it appear higher in the list of results returned for related searches.

Comment: What about the overflowed element ? is it considered scrollable ? I've tried it but it didn't work. Why is that so ? @tao

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255746/discussion-between-tao-and-reynald-lamury).